# actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex is not work in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I try to click button, select from action sheet and then set the selected index to the button text label's text. My button is below. But it not show selected index in button text. How can I solve this?

```
- (IBAction)cinsiyetBtnClick:(id)sender {
    popupQuery1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cinsiyetiniz" 
                                              delegate:self 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:NO 
                                destructiveButtonTitle:NO 
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Bay", @"Bayan",nil];
    popupQuery1.tag = 1;
    //    popupQuery1.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [popupQuery1 showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [popupQuery1 release];
}

- (IBAction)medeniDurumBtnClick:(id)sender {
    popupQuery1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Medeni Durumunuz" 
                                              delegate:self 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:NO 
                                destructiveButtonTitle:NO 
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Evli", @"Bekar",@"Dul",@"Boşanmış",nil];
    popupQuery1.tag = 2;
    //    popupQuery1.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [popupQuery1 showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [popupQuery1 release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(actionSheet.tag==1){
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            self.cinsiyetBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Bay";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            self.cinsiyetBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Bayan";
        } 
    }
    else if (actionSheet.tag == 2){
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            self.medeniDurumBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Evli";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            self.medeniDurumBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Bekar";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
            self.medeniDurumBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Dul";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
            self.medeniDurumBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Boşanmış";
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set the UIApplicationDelegate in .h file?

Comment: so what is exactly the problem....NO button title is updating??

Answer (score 1):

There are several states in which button could be: `UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateHighlighted`, `UIControlStateSelected` and `UIControlStateDisabled`.

In most cases when you want to update title of button you should set new title for normal state:

```
[button setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Sometimes you would need to set titles for all the states.

So now you should just replace all your `self.cinsiyetBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Bay";` with something like this:

```
[self.cinsiyetBtn setTitle:@"Bay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```